# Make a PHP string display on multiple lines in a textarea, using a specified character to split it

Tags: php, string, textarea, newline

I have options stored in the database in the following format -

`option1:Option 1;option2:Option 2;option3:Option 3;option4:Option 4`

Users are able to edit these options, so when they are in the `<textarea>` I'd like for them to be displayed on seperate lines.

```
option1:Option 1
option2:Option 2
option3:Option 3
option4:Option 4
```

I'm trying to do this by replacing the `';'` character that seperates the options with a new line (`str_replace(';', PHP_EOL, $poll['poll_options'])` - have also tried `"\r\n"`)

Even though this appears to be working (`echo '<pre>'; print_r($poll['poll_options']); echo '</pre>';` shows the options correcty on a new line), when I place the text in a `<textarea>` the options are only seperated be a space.

**Edit** - I've changed the code I used (now reflected in this post) to that suggested by @John Conde, and it now works in FF.

Any tips on how to resolve? Thanks.

Comment: Hm, can you show us the resulting HTML source? Because this works here....

Comment: that is NOT a `<textarea>`, that is a `<div>`.... Which (unless css's `white-space:pre` is set) will _never_ show newlines (see also [a quick reference to white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a donut - It is a textbox, but I use an AJAX call to display an inline edit row, with the fields (including the `<textarea>` being populated from that hidden data that is created when the page loads. Just trying to workout how to get that AJAX source now...

Comment: Why hide that data in DOM elements which can do all kinds of weird stuff / optimization to it? I'd load the output of `json_encode()` in a javascript variable, and a lot less nastiness happens to it's actual contents.

Comment: Hmm, I alread do that with a few variables, but I would have to make wholesale changes to the way that my editing works to impliment it here. It's looking more and more like this in only IE related now (surprise, surprise!), so I think I'll leave it this time, but will take your advise onboard for the future.

Comment: Well, if you are just hiding that data anyway.... Why not make that hidden thingamayig a `textarea` instead of a `div`? Still accessible, and MSIE is more likely to not fiddle with whitespace inside it.

Comment: Think I'd still have to make some slight changes, but that would be far easier for this particular project. Will look in to that tomorrow when I'm back at work. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I've jigged a few things around, and I've placed the hidden content in a `<textarea>` as opposed to a `<div>` but I still get the same result. Next step will be to try the `json_encode()` approach, but it may take a few days to get a result as I'll need to make quite a few changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$new_text = str_replace(';', PHP_EOL, $poll['poll_options']);
```

[`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is easier to work with then regular expressions.

Comment: ALthough `str_replace` may be more apt here, the `PHP_EOL` (= line anding on server, not client) does not give any more benefits, and it will probably not solve the OPs problem as you are only addressing a coding preference / arguably better practice, but not the problem the OP mentioned.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to directly use `\r\n` instead of `PHP_EOL` here?

Comment: No, I think you are right to advocate `PHP_EOL` here, but most likely it will just  _result_ in `\n` or `\r\n`, both of which browsers can deal with just fine. So: you are right about advocating both `str_replace` & `PHP_EOL`, but I doubt it addresses the problem the OP is having. Using it would improve his code, but the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Have change to your suggestion above, and the results are the same in IE, but now working in FF. The source is showing that the string is broken on to a new line, but it's just not displaying like that. Thanks.